# Tiny Wings Gameplay

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, libgdx, game-physics, game-development

I got the reference from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32958/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-2) User have to apply a force to the character to push him down. That will make him go quickly down slopes, giving him velocity that will make him fly up .But with the figures provided there, When character runs down the slopes it speeds up way too fast and the user does not get much time to release the button. Like in tiny wings, bird moves around hills in good speed not too fast and user gets enough time to release the button and get perfect fly.

Basically how can i store the energy of bird without moving fast along slopes, so that it can fly at the right time.
Any suggestion why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the bird is colliding with the slopes. If YES, don't apply the force in the `dive` method... Instead, store energy and apply it when bird leave the slope.

Comment: Well thanks for suggestion but i have that thing in my mind before i raised my question here just asking how to implement this theoritical idea.

Comment: Note:-May be you understood or,you have not played Tiny Wings . Bird is always colliding with slope (Moving Upward And Downward) while we are supposed to activate dive only if going downward (This thing is done) secondly You can't say don't activate dive while bird is on slope cause it will change the dynamics and it will efffect the feel .

Comment: the problems are :                                                     1) How to Store Energy ,which will increase with dive button press and decrease if release.                                                  2)Bird is not supposed to leave the slope without any external energy like from dive button Press/Release at right time.

Comment: Try to check the angle of collision between the bird and slope, to find it is a upward or downward slope. Maybe physics will solve the increase/decrease velocity when landed ok or not ok on a slope... And can also check the Y velocity of bird to find if it is going down or up, to make some adjusts on physics forces

Comment: Mauricio have you played Tiny Wings ? I have done all those steps you're specifying here and mentioned there in blog . Again problem's are : 1) How to Store Energy ,which will increase with dive button press and decrease if release. 2)Bird is not supposed to leave the slope without any external energy like from dive button Press/Release at right time.

Comment: Yes. I played it. You can store energy in a property increased and controlled by your game logic. For example, if bird is colliding with slope, and are going downward, and diving, you accumulate on this property a value on gameLoop. Then, when your bird stop touching the ground (leaving the slope), you can apply this stored energy to increase its fly (or decrease the bird power if player not landed right)